# Finding annotated methods in application code from maven integration test

Tags: java, reflection, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have a custom annotation in my program that I apply to methods. I would like to find all methods with a particular annotation. From my application code, I can use the Reflections package to do so:

```
new Reflections(
    new ConfigurationBuilder().setUrls(
        ClasspathHelper.forPackage("com.my.package")
    ).setScanners(new MethodAnnotationsScanner())
    ).getMethodsAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class);
```

However, when I try to do the same from an integration test invoked via `failsafe` to find the annotated methods in the application (not in the test), no methods are found. How can I get my annotated methods from an integration test?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: @Code-Apprentice What's lacking from your perspective?

Comment: You should provide the code which you are describing in English.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I did provide code. I'm unclear on what's missing.

Comment: The code you have given is not **complete**. Please read the link I gave above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two things I had to change to get things to work:

1. I was using version 0.9.9-RC1. I was careless enough to first discover Reflections at https://code.google.com/archive/p/reflections/, which lists 0.9.9-RC1 as the latest version, and did not notice the small print mentioning that the project had moved to GitHub. I assumed 0.9.9-RC1 was the latest version, which was not the case. The latest as of the time of writing was 0.9.11.
2. I changed the `Reflections` instantiation as follows:

   new Reflections("com.my.package", new MethodAnnotationsScanner());